# Is there a css selector to match a option value of the select tag?

Tags: css, selector

For example:

```
<select>
<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

I want to select the option where value = one, but I must select using the value attribute.

I've tried a few variations as the ones below:

```
option[value="one"]{
}

select[value="one"]{
}

select option[value="one"]{
}
```

Comment: The first and third selectors work fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```css
option[value=two] { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works fine with the quotes too.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it works with or without quotes. For some reason it was not working before, but it is now.

Comment: Quotes should be used for string values. Only certain values work without them (namely, "identifier tokens", like a language identifier). See https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-selectors

Comment: Is it possible to keep the yellow background even when two is selected? So the select box is yellow?

Comment: Warning that Safari does not support this.

Comment: doesn't work in chrome latest either (as for 2023)